# How do I declare the identifier in this smart contract?

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

Find you can find any potential errors or something that can cause an issue, please help me fix them now. Thank you for can preventing me from any troubles ahead. :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3V9x.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.